# Some unicode aren't displayed

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I'd like to use following unicode:
content: '\e808';
content: '\e80b';

When I try to instert them into html, they are displayed as rectangles. Seems that I need to add support font to head of the page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These are codepoints in the "private use area".  A font can use it to display special glyphs that are not part of Unicode.  Seeing nothing at all is thus entirely normal, it is not clear why you expected to see anything.  Use a tool that can show the glyphs supported by the font you use.

Comment: Can you be so kind to point which tool to use to detect glyphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notations `'\e808'` and `'\e80b'` (in CSS) refer to the [Private Use](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) codepoints U+E808 and U+E80B. Private Use means that no meaning is assigned to them in the Unicode standard. A font may or may not contain glyphs assigned to those codepoints; this depends on the decisions of the font designer, and there is no reason to expect any consistency here.

Thus, you should decide which characters you wish to use and to find the Unicode codepoints assigned to them.